# Excel partial search column from list and populate adjacent cells

Tags: excel, list, search

I have found similar questions and answers but not enough to complete this, though I think it's possible, without resorting to VBA?

[image: Screen shot of data sample]

I have 1000s of rows in Column C. At present, I use Data Validation in columns N and O, with lists from columns S and T, controlled to a degree, but tedious.
I think I need a formula in column Q in each row, and if column N is blank (not already processed), look for column R in Column C, then populate column N and O with the values form the found row, if any, from columns S and T and leave it blank otherwise.
I don't want the formula in columns N and O as I need to keep the data validation for manual selection for any not found in column R.

I hope that makes sense and is the best solution? Many thanks in advance. First post so I hope image shows okay.

Comment: You can't do that.  A formula in Column Q can only return a value to Column Q.  If you need to alter the contents of columns N and O without having a formula in those columns, you will need a VBA macro (or data validation to only allow certain entries).

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that, but thinking about it, how would I do it with formulae in Column N please?

Comment: From the limited sample you show, I'd suggest either `VLOOKUP`, `XLOOKUP`, or `INDEX(MATCH(...` where `lookup_value` is the portion of `Transaction Description` prior to the first `space`.

Comment: Looks like I'll be using VBA as I can't have a formulae and validation on the same cell.
I am aware of those functions but don't have enough experience to combine them to get what I want

Comment: If you have the formula looking up the values, you don't need validation.

Comment: But there needs to be manual options for controlled change of the cells.
Thanks for your help, I'm writing the VBA now :-)